# Unique throw to SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: laravel

The error happend after migrate:refresh

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `phone` where `phone_number` = 0883991010 and `id` <> )
```

I have no idea but maybe it cause by unique validation

here is my Request for the Controller

```
   if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
        $name_rules = 'required|string|size:4|unique:student,name,' . $this->get('id');
        $phone_rules = 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:phone,phone_number,' . $this->get('id') . ',id_student';
    }

    else {
        $name_rules = 'required|string|size:4|unique:student,name,';
        $phone_rules = 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:phone,phone_number,';
    }
```

**Phone.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'phone';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_student';

    protected $fillable = [

        'id_student',
        'phone_number',
    ];



    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'id_student');
    }
}
```

**Schema**

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('phone', function (Blueprint $table) 
    {

        $table->integer('id_student')->unsigned()->primary('id_student');
        $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('id_student')->references('id')->on('tudent')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    }); 

}
```

it works fine when i get rid unique:phone,phone_number,

Any better suggestion?

Comment: whats the table name where you store phone number ?

Comment: Check phone_number attribute column in the table.

Comment: But... there's no database activity in those lines of code.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi the table name is phone

Comment: show your table schema

Comment: table phone must have a column name same as $phone_rules

Comment: @SapneshNaik kindly check my schema

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi yes it already have a column name the same as phone rules

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your custom primary key in each of the validation checks but you are doing it in only of them.

**Try this**

```
   if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
        $name_rules = 'required|string|size:4|unique:student,name,' . $this->get('id'). ',id_student';
        $phone_rules = 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:phone,phone_number,' . $this->get('id') . ',id_student';
    }

    else {
        $name_rules = 'required|string|size:4|unique:student,name,' . $this->get('id'). ',id_student';
        $phone_rules = 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:phone,phone_number,' . $this->get('id') . ',id_student';
    }
```

Comment: @YudyAnanda was this answer correct?. If yes then you can mark the answer as right!

Comment: it doesnt make any change, it is still the same error.  right now i'm not using the request so I put the error validation back to the controller (store & update)  do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you, I fixed it by enclosing the field of type VARCHAR in double quotes.
Try this:

```
if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
    $name_rules = 'required|string|size:4|unique:student,name,' . $this->get('id');
    $phone_rules = 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:phone,"phone_number",' . $this->get('id') . ',id_student';
}
else {
    $name_rules = 'required|string|size:4|unique:student,name,';
    $phone_rules = 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:phone,"phone_number",';
}
```